# Update with BoundFields in asp:GridView asp:SQLDataSource leads to System.ArgumentException PageValidation Error

Tags: asp.net

There is a growing table (aspx Site) in an iFrame with asp:GridView and SQLDataSource, that refreshes on an event in the parent site.

I have added the possibility to edit the GridView by Adding the ActionCommand "Delete, Update, Edit" to it. In order to do this, i have added an UpdateCommand to the SQLDataSource.

DELETE works - UPDATE not.

The problem is, that i get System.ArgumentException:with unvalidated PostBack or Callbackargument. 
When i change the asp:CommandField to "ButtonType" = "Link" there is no page validation error , but when i change the "ButtonType" to "Image" i get a Page Validation error (see screenshot). 
Both ButtonType-Selections do not Update the Data.

[image: Page Validation Error]

I have added the UpdateParamaters Section to it but it has no effect - same error. I have added EnableEventValidation="false" to the top of the page - the error disappears (like with ButtonType=Link) but no update will be performed.

```
    <asp:GridView DataKeyNames="id" CssClass="tableStyle" ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="BelDat" HeaderText="Created on" SortExpression="BelDat" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"  />
            <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="PersNr" HeaderText="Pers No." SortExpression="PersNr" />
            <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="lblPortfolio" HeaderText="Portfolio" SortExpression="lblPortfolio" />
            <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="lblProject" HeaderText="Project" SortExpression="lblProject" />
            <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="lblPSPElement" HeaderText="Element" SortExpression="lblPSPElement" />
            <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="PSPElement" HeaderText="CC/Contract/PSP Element" SortExpression="PSPElement" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Text50Stellen" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Text50Stellen" />
            <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="Menge" HeaderText="Hours" SortExpression="Menge" DataFormatString="{0:n1}" />
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" CancelImageUrl="~/Images/cancel.png" DeleteImageUrl="~/Images/trash.png" EditImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" UpdateImageUrl="~/Images/save.png" />
        </Columns>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            (nothing has been logged in this month)
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" UpdateCommand="UPDATE timesheet SET Text50Stellen=@Text50Stellen WHERE id=@id" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM timesheet WHERE id=@id" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DP_TimeSheetConnectionString %>">
        <UpdateParameters>
              <asp:Parameter Name="Text50Stellen" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This is my code in the code behind section for Page_Load:

```
public void refreshDataGrid()
{
    SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = MyConfigurationManager.prdSqlServerString;
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = @" 
            SELECT [id], 
                   [username], 
                   [BuDat], 
                   [BelDat], 
                   [PersNr], 
                   [SendKst], 
                   [Menge], 
                   [Lar], 
                   ISNULL([EmpfKst],'')+
                   ISNULL([EmpfAufn],'')+
                   ISNULL([EmpfPSPE],'') as PSPElement, 
                   [EmpfKundenauftrag], 
                   [Po], 
                   [EmpfNetzplan], 
                   [EmpfVorgang],
                   [Text50Stellen],
                   [lblPortfolio],
                   [lblProject],
                   [lblPSPElement]
            FROM   [timesheet] 
            WHERE  username='";

    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand += new AuthenticationService().getUsername().Trim() + "' ";

    if (Request.QueryString["month"] != null && Request.QueryString["year"] != null)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand += " AND MONTH(BuDat)=" + Request.QueryString["month"] + " AND YEAR(BuDat)=" + Request.QueryString["year"] + " ";
        GridView1.Columns[GridView1.Columns.Count - 1].Visible = false;
    } 
    else
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand += " AND MONTH(BuDat)=MONTH(GetDate()) AND YEAR(BuDat)=YEAR(GetDate()) ";
    }

    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand += " ORDER BY id DESC ";

    SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    refreshDataGrid();
}
```

The Problem is, when i ask for if(!IsPostBack) before refreshing the asp:DataGrid, the Table is not loaded

```
[ArgumentException: Ungültiges Postback- oder Callbackargument. Die Ereignisvalidierung wird mithilfe von <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in der Konfiguration oder mithilfe von <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> auf einer Seite aktiviert. Aus Sicherheitsgründen überprüft dieses Feature, dass Argumente für Postback- oder Callbackereignisse von dem Serversteuerelement ausgehen, von dem sie ursprünglich gerendert wurden. Wenn die Daten gültig sind und erwartet wurden, verwenden Sie die ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation-Methode, um die Postback- oder Callbackdaten für die Validierung zu registrieren.]
   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId, String argument) +9756058
   System.Web.UI.Control.ValidateEvent(String uniqueID, String eventArgument) +108
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +29
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1639
```

S.th. i found out:
When i change the asp:CommandField to the following code - the PageValidation Error disappears, but the Update isn't working:

```
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" 
                EditText="<img src='Images/edit.png' style='border-width:0' />" 
                DeleteText="<img src='Images/trash.png' style='border-width:0' />"
                CancelText="<img src='Images/cancel.png' style='border-width:0' />"
                UpdateText="<img src='Images/save.png' style='border-width:0' />"
                />
```

Comment: Try using `if (!IsPostBack)` on `Page_Load` event if you bound something on that event. If you use `RowEditing`, set `e.Cancel = true` after doing an edit.

Comment: Thx this is a possibility for the correct solution. I just have added what i have done. Problem with !IsPostBack is, that nothing will be shown on Refresh (it is a growing Table in an iFrame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly shure what is different now but now it works with Tetsuya Yamamotos hint.

if(!IsPostBack) GridView1.DataBind();

```
    <asp:GridView DataKeyNames="id" CssClass="tableStyle" ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="BelDat" HeaderText="Created on" SortExpression="BelDat" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"  />
            <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="PersNr" HeaderText="Pers No." SortExpression="PersNr" />
            <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="lblPortfolio" HeaderText="Portfolio" SortExpression="lblPortfolio" />
            <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="lblProject" HeaderText="Project" SortExpression="lblProject" />
            <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="lblPSPElement" HeaderText="Element" SortExpression="lblPSPElement" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Text50Stellen" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Text50Stellen" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Menge" HeaderText="Hours" SortExpression="Menge" DataFormatString="{0:n1}" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" 
                EditText="<img src='Images/edit.png' style='border-width:0' />" 
                DeleteText="<img src='Images/trash.png' style='border-width:0' />"
                CancelText="<img src='Images/cancel.png' style='border-width:0' />"
                UpdateText="<img src='Images/save.png' style='border-width:0' />"
                />
        </Columns>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            (nothing has been logged in this month)
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
            <!--<CommandField CancelImageUrl="~/Images/cancel.png" DeleteImageUrl="~/Images/trash.png" EditImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" UpdateImageUrl="~/Images/save.png" />-->
    <!--       nach lblPSPElement          <BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="PSPElement" HeaderText="CC/Contract/PSP Element" SortExpression="PSPElement" /> -->
    <asp:SqlDataSource 
        ID="SqlDataSource1" 
        runat="server" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE timesheet SET Text50Stellen=@Text50Stellen, Menge=@Menge WHERE id=@id" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM timesheet WHERE id=@id" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DP_TimeSheetConnectionString %>">
        <UpdateParameters>
              <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Text50Stellen" Type="String" />
              <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Menge" Type="Decimal" />
              <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="id" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```